# Clojure: Return an Iterator for a java for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, clojure, iterator

Lets say I have a for loop in Java:

```
 for(Foo foo : foos){ do_something() }
```

Now lets say I want to translate this list iteration to idiomatic clojure.  Whats the best way?  I want to return something I can use like an iterator over the foos collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(doseq [foo foos]
  (do-something))
```

is the idiomatic Clojure equivalent of your Java snippet.

As for returning an iterator, Clojure's collections are all `Iterable` and seqable, so you can iterate over them in the idiomatic way in both Clojure and Java.

Comment: This is great thanks.  One more question, Im used to higher order Perl function closures, where I would wrap the iterator in something like this:  `my $func = _build_iterator();  while( my $next_val = $func->() ) { do_something( $next_val) }`  what is the clojure way to do this?

Comment: Idea is to close over the calls to the results of an hbase scan in some convenient processing before giving the result back to the user: `(defmethod scan [java.lang.String java.lang.String] [table start-key end-key]
    (let [scan (Scan. (Bytes/toBytes start-key) (Bytes/toBytes end-key))]
        (let [scanner (.getScanner table scan)]
            (doseq [result scanner]
                (prn
                    (Bytes/toString (.getRow result))
                    (get-to-map result))))))`
I want to return an iterator that unwraps the row key and return a suitable value like nil when exhausted

Comment: I see you posted a new question; I'll answer over there. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16328566 for the interested.)

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong.  I'm keeping this around so that it provides useful information for others though**

```
(dorun (map (constantly (do-something)) foos))
```

[Here's the definition of `map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) and [here's the definition of `constantly`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/constantly).

In summary, this will call `do-something` for each element in foos.  `constantly` will ignore anything you pass in and just do what you tell it to.

Comment: `map` is lazy -- you'd have to wrap it in `dorun` to ensure the effects actually take place. `doall` is another possibility, but it will hold onto the head of the sequence, which is undesirable here.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk changed, but I'm not necessarily sure if I should have.  Depending on what he does next, the original thing I posted could be equivalent, right?

Comment: There's actually another more important problem -- `(map (constantly (do-something)) ...)` will only `(do-something)` once, before the iteration even begins. You'd need something like `(map (fn [_] (do-something)) ...)` instead.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Yeah I'm way off.  I'm going to keep this around (unless it gets downvotes) because your comments have useful info in it.

Comment: As for equivalence of the snippets (with `(fn [_] ...)`), it's certainly possible to force the lazy seq in the caller of `map`, but why do it if the whole point of iterating is to produce some effects while throwing away the result? That delegates the responsibility for making sure the effects happen in a timely manner -- in fact, that they happen at all -- to the caller, which feels a bit fragile. Plus `doseq` is likely to perform somewhat better, since it does away with the lazy seq allocation altogether (whereas `map` will always construct it; `dorun` then throws it away piece by piece).