# Clojure and HBase: Iterate Lazily over a Scan

Tags: java, clojure, iterator, hbase, sequence

Lets say I want to print the output of an hbase table scan in clojure.

```
(defmulti scan (fn [table & args] (map class args)))

(defmethod scan [java.lang.String java.lang.String] [table start-key end-key]
    (let [scan (Scan. (Bytes/toBytes start-key) (Bytes/toBytes end-key))]
        (let [scanner (.getScanner table scan)]
            (doseq [result scanner]
                (prn
                    (Bytes/toString (.getRow result))
                    (get-to-map result))))))
```

where get-to-map turns the result into a map.  It could be run like this:

```
(hbase.table/scan table "key000001" "key999999")
```

But what if I want to let the user do something with the scan results?  I could allow them to pass a function in as a callback to be applied to each result.  But my question is this: what do I return if I want the user to be able to lazily iterate over the each result

```
(Bytes/toString (.getRow result))
(get-to-map result)
```

*and* not retain the previous results, as might happen in a simplistic implimentation with lazy-seq.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a callback argument, you can just call it inside the `doseq`:

```
(defmulti scan [f table & args] (mapv class args)) ; mapv returns vector

(defmethod scan [String String] [f table start-key end-key]
               ; ^- java.lang classes are imported implicitly
  (let [scan ...
        scanner ...] ; no need for two separate lets
    (doseq [result scanner]
      ; call f here, e.g.
      (f result))))
```

Here `f` will be called once per result. Its return value, as well as the result itself, will be discarded immediately. You can of course call `f` with some preprocessed version of `result`, e.g. `(f (foo result) (bar result))`.

You could also return a sequence / vector of results to the client and let it do its own processing. If the sequence is lazy, you need to make sure that any resources backing it stay open for the duration of the processing (and presumably that they are closed later -- see `with-open`; the processing code would need to execute inside the `with-open` and be done with the processing when it returns).

For example, to return a vector of preprocessed results to the client you could do

```
(defmethod scan ...
  (let [...]
    (mapv (fn preprocess-result [result]
            (result->map result))
          scanner)))
```

The client can then do whatever it wants with them. Use `map` to return a lazy sequence instead. If the client then needs to open/close a resource, you could accept it as an argument to scan, so that the client could say

```
(with-open [r (some-resource)]
  ; or mapv, dorun+map, doall+for, ...
  (doseq [result (scan r ...)]
    (do-stuff-with result)))
```

Comment: Got it thanks.  Where I am at right now is returning a function that calls next on the result scanner until its exhausted

`#(let [result (.next result-scanner)]
            (if (not= result nil)
                [(Bytes/toString (.getRow result)) (get-to-map result)]
                nil))`

Next thing im working on understanding is then how to concisely call that function until it returns nil, then break out.

`(let [cursor (hbase.table/scan table "k1" "r2")] ... )`

Comment: Sure. I've edited the answer to add two examples of how to get preprocessed results to the client. Returning a collection -- often a lazy sequence -- to the client is much more usual in Clojure than using Java iterators or any workalikes. Another solution would be to return a reducer; you'd need to be on Clojure 1.5 for that, but then you could do your preprocessing with `r/map`, have the client do its own `r/map` (or whatever) and be free of any worries of intermediate allocations. The general feel of the code stays very similar.

Comment: See Rich's blog posts for information on reducers: [introduction](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/08/reducers-a-library-and-model-for-collection-processing.html), [follow-up](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/15/anatomy-of-reducer.html). Note that if you're reducing a lazy sequence, the usual caveat about closing underlying resources applies.

Comment: Understood, I think my main concern was if those list get large, like an hbase scan could be very big, but I want to use it as a stream.  Best I did so far is this:

`(let [cursor (hbase.table/scan table "k1" "r2")]
    (loop [result nil]
        (let [result (cursor)]
            (prn result)
            (if (not= nil result)
                (recur nil)))))`
problem is it prints a final nil, which is er, annoying, but the recur has to be in the tail position ...

Comment: If HBase gives you an iterator, then you can just iterate over it in a `doseq` and in that you *will* be using it as a stream (no previous results will be held on to). You can also wrap the iterator in a lazy seq -- `(map f iter)` -- and pass that to clients; if the clients then process this using `doseq`, they'll still be using it as a stream (initial fragments of the lazy seq will become eligible for GC as soon as processing moves past them). You just need to make sure you close the resource at the correct momment, which is true with any approach anyway; `with-open` helps with that.

Comment: Actually, about the "simplistic implementation with lazy-seq" you mention in the question text -- Clojure is quite dilligent in not holding on to the heads of lazy seqs unless you force it to, see for example this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994316/clojure-head-retention and the related Clojure Google group discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/bTAYeLXc25w/cZpMfIN4l5MJ

Comment: It looks like the motivation for those posts from Clojure Programming (where I read about head retention from the same example too) is that unless you use split-with, clojure *does* hang on to the cached realized values.  Is that wrong?

Comment: It is wrong. Clojure clears local references to lazy seqs as soon as they're no longer needed (assuming they are used at least once, e.g. as arguments in a function call; completely unused locals are not cleared IIRC); seq functions then throw away their input seqs piece by piece. For example try `(let [xs (range 1000000000)] (last xs))`; at no point does this hold a billion `long`s in memory. Also note that in the linked question, both the working and the non-working examples use `split-with`; the point is that the non-working one forces a reference to the huge seq to stay alive too long.